# Restrict input keys

Tags: javascript

I have an input field and want to be able to limit the characters entered only by this set `[0-0][a-z][A-Z].-_`

The question is that the character <kbd>`</kbd> is not blocked and appears in the input field. All characters are blocked except that one and in my database should not be entered that kind of character.

The code is:

```
$.fn.restrict = function(pattern, allowed){
    allowed = allowed || [0, 46, 8, 9, 27, 13]; 
    $(this).keypress(function(event){
        if(event.which) {
            var key = event.which;
            if($.inArray(key, allowed) > -1){
              return true;   
            }
            var character = String.fromCharCode(key);
            if(pattern.test(character)){
                return true;
            }
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        };
    });
    return this;
};
```

Any idea how could I solve this?

Comment: you should filter that on your serverside as well.

Comment: Don't. Let me type what I want. Tell me that it's invalid later if you must, but don't stop me from typing. I have a backspace key and I will use it, thanks very much.

Comment: is that the actual regex you are passing as `pattern`? that will indeed block everything, including "`"

Comment: pattern is a regex expression. I have: $('input[type="text"]').restrict(/[a-z][0-9].-_/);

Answer (score 0):

You could on keydown store the current verified value and on keyup or keypress verify the new value against your pattern  and if the new values doesn't comply restore the old value